# generate activesync profile for lock/wipe via php

Tags: android, ios, exchange-server, mdm, activesync

I'm trying to write a web service offerring a hosted ActiveSync-management service where, via a Web interface, customers can do things like lock / wipe / reset / turn off/on features like Bluetooth, etc.

Is it possible to push down ActiveSync profiles via a web service down to mobile devices (iOS , Android, Windows phone) in order to do this ? Or does this work only if Exchange Server sends it to the device ?

Answer (score 0):

Several notes:

**MDM is not ActiceSync**

Usually, MDM is standalone protocol/interface with it's own set of commands. And ActiveSync is another protocol/interface with another set of commands.

**Push down ActiveSync profiles**

It's not clear what do you mean. Are you talking about pushing ActiveSync account configuration (to point device to specific exchange) or are you talking about sending ActiveSync commands?

**Sending ActiveSync commands**

You have to implement server side of ActiveSync protocol to send ActiveSync commands. It could be done several ways:

- You use Exchange Server and send commands through it (frankly, I am not sure what kind of Exchange provides to automate it)
- You can use some filter installed before your Exchange Server which will inject commands on the fly
- You can implement the whole things and you won't need Exchange in such cae.